# Android - SortedList.indexOf() returns INVALID_POSITION

Tags: android, sortedlist

I have come across a very strange behavior of [`SortedList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.html). The method [`indexOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.html#indexOf(T)) returns [`INVALID_POSITION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.html#INVALID_POSITION) even though in the debugger everything seems okay.

[image]

Method `getWorkingDayItems` of adapter `workingDayAdapter` returns `SortedList`.

As you can see, the 3rd element of the list is `WorkingDay@4678` which is the same object as object `workingDay`. Yet the method `indexOf` returns **-1**.

Could you explain to me, why is this happening? Is there a known or not yet discovered but in the `SortedList`? Or is there another cause?

Thank you.

EDIT:

After removing overriding of `equals` method the problem persist.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case it's because I modified attribute **localStatus** of my object after adding items to the list, which is also being used in **compare** method,
and **SortedList** uses binary search base on the output of **compare** method.

Here is my **compare** method

```
@Override
public int compare(SmsWrapper o1, SmsWrapper o2) {
    return o1.localStatus.ordinal() - o2.localStatus.ordinal();
}
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

In normal lists in java the indexOf() method compares with the equals() method (I haven't found it for SortedList). Could it be the problem that you haven't overriden the equals() method in your WorkingDay class? I think if you pass a new instance of WorkingDay@4678 into your indexOf() method it would classify it with -1.

Comment: Actually the question is not answered, I have edited the question

Comment: Sorry, then I also don't know the answer. Does it work for any item or is it every time -1 (also when you use workingDays you didn't get from your SortedList)?